# critical package ctex error:ctex fontset"fandol" is unavailable in current

Tags: polyglossia, ctex

I am trying to use some Chinese characters in my Latex document(But it is not entirely in Chinese) and [this](https://jdhao.github.io/2018/03/29/latex-chinese.zh/) is the website that I came across. According to the author, all I need is to use ctex package, but when I copy paste the example code in his website it failed to compile with the error message *critical package ctex error:ctex fontset"fandol" is unavailable in current* I wonder what went wrong? And if his method is incorrect, I wonder if there is another way that allow me to type Chinese successfuly. (I can not change the documentclass as I am trying to use a poster theme template and the documentclass ,I assume, is predefined.)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
你好，这是一个测试文档。
\end{document}
```

[image]
edit: include the error message and picture
edit2: uploaded the wrong one. inlcude the correct picture[!

Comment: your example works for me with pdflatex + windows + a current texlive.

Comment: added the picture. It is not compilable on my Macbook. Do you think it has anything to do with font selection on my local computer? But it also failed to compile on overleaf.

Comment: You are using xelatex, so remove \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}. Beside this: "warning" is a warning/info not an error. Check if the output is okay.

Comment: Sorry I uploaded the wrong picture. You are right it is compilable using XeLaTex, But when I tried to compile it on LaTex, the compilation was not successful. Would you be kind enough to point out what went wrong? I am not sure my other code, which was written with Latex in mind, can be compiled in XeLaTex without any problem.

Comment: try to set another fontset, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/284933/2388

Comment: `ctex` classes/package will automatically select different fontset according to OS. When using windows, it will use `simsum.ttf` etc, which can be compiled with pdflatex; but on macos/linux, it will use other fonts and can't be compiled with pdflatex. However, you may use latex+dvipdfmx, or much simpler, xelatex or lualatex.

Comment: Replace the engine `xelatex` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use `pdflatex` to compile Chinese documents that specify `fandol` fonts because

> 使用Fandol中文字体，不支持pdfLaTeX。
>
> Using Fandol Chinese fonts, pdfLaTeX is not supported.

Reference `texdoc ctex`, *sec 4.3中文字库*

You may need to install other Chinese fonts, such as: Source Han Serif

Comment: I don’t understand when did I specify that

Comment: @jxhyc If a fontset value is not specified, the CTEX macro set will automatically detect the operating system used by the user and configure the appropriate font. So Overleaf specifies by default that fandol, Mac OS X compiler Chinese is not available under pdflatex.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me

if your content goes like this

```tex
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}  
\begin{document}  
    中文输入  
\end{document}
```

Just add this line `%!TEX program = xelatex` to the top of your `TeX` file like this:

```tex
%!TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}  
\begin{document}  
    中文输入  
\end{document}
```

Thanks to the blog: http://fangda.me/2018/10/23/Latex%E5%8A%A0%E5%85%A5%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87%E5%8C%85%E7%9A%84%E9%94%99%E8%AF%AF%E5%A4%84%E7%90%86/

Answer (score 1):

The first answer is correct. Fandol does not support pdflatex.

To fix, simply change your compiler away from pdflatex: Menu --> Complier --> choose any of the other compliers.